# JavaFX FinishListener idle method called twice

Tags: java, javafx

I add a FinishListener to the JavaFX Application and if I close the last Window the idle method will be called twice.

Why the idle method called twice?

```
PlatformImpl.addListener(new PlatformImpl.FinishListener() {
    @Override
    public void idle(boolean implicitExit) {
        System.out.println("Idle " + implicitExit);
    }

    @Override
    public void exitCalled() {
        System.out.println("Exit called");
    }
});

//Output after closing the window by pressing x on the top right:
Idle true
Idle true
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not adding 2 listeners (that you don't call PlatformImpl.addListener twice)?

Comment: Could you provide us an SSCCE?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I only add only one listener. But I have a Preloader and if I remove the Preloader it only calls one time the idle() method. But I don't add a second listener to the Preloader

Comment: May I ask why this is a problem? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It's not a problem I basically can set a boolean value to true by the first call to skip the second one. I just wondering why it calls twice.

Comment: I guess I'm more curious about why you're adding a listener at all since this deals with internal code. What action are you trying to take when `idle(boolean)` is invoked?